# How to create keys from lists and get key-value pairs from tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I have tuples in a dataframe that look like this:

|  | items |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | (strawberry, ice cream) |
| 1 | (apple, banana, biscuits) |

I have also two separate lists of "fruit" and "snack".

```
fruit = ["strawberry", "apple", "banana"]
snack = ["ice cream", "biscuits"]
```

How do I change them to key:value pairs that look like this:

|  | items |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | {"fruit": "strawberry" , "snack": "ice cream"} |
| 1 | {"fruit": ["apple", "banana"] , "snack": "biscuits"} |

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You could consider a different approach altogether. Instead of having dictionaries as values you could have a MultiIndex column with level 1 = items and level 2 = fruit, snack. This will allow you to access data much faster, save memory, and have a cleaner representation of your data. If you like it I'll post an answer.

Comment: That would definitely help, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You haven't provided that much information. Based on your sample data :

```
df1 =pd.DataFrame()
df1['items'] = [('strawberry', 'ice cream'), ('apple', 'banana', 'biscuits')]
```

A solution would be to make a simple function associating each item with his category.

```
def findCategory(x):
    fruit = ["strawberry", "apple", "banana"]
    snack = ["ice cream", "biscuits"]

    result = {
        'fruit': [],
        'snack': []
    }

    for item in x['items']:
        if item in fruit:
            result['fruit'].append(item)
        elif item in snack:
            result['snack'].append(item)

    return result
```

Then you can apply that function on each row of your `DataFrame` with `apply()` :

```
df1['items'] = df1.apply(findCategory, axis=1)
# Output
                                               items
0  {'fruit': ['strawberry'], 'snack': ['ice cream']}
1  {'fruit': ['apple', 'banana'], 'snack': ['bisc...
```

The `findCategory()` function created above is working specifically for your example, but can be generalised with more categories, and with dictionnary comprehension if you are confortable with it.